# perl regexp minimal match the word before underscore

Tags: regex, perl

may i know how to write the regexp for this case?

```
$aword = abc_def_ghi regexp substitute to abc_def_xxx
$bword = jkl_mno_pqr regexp substitute to jkl_mno_xxx
$cword = abc_def     regexp substitute to abc_xxx
```

Zh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$aword = 'abc_def_ghi';
$aword =~ s/[^_]+$/xxx/;  # [^_]+$: to match non-underscore at the end of string.
print $aword  # => abc_def_xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/^[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*_\K[a-z]+\z/xxx/
```

In strings composed solely of two or more "words" of letters a through z, replace the last "word" with xxx.

You can read about regexes in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

```
^ \z: zero width assertions
[]: character class
+ *: quantifiers
(?: ): extended pattern (clustering)
\K: special escape
```

Comment: If you told me which part is ugly, you would probably be telling me which part you need elaborated?

Comment: Everything so that any newcomer can understand it. I do not mean _your_ regex being ugly, but regex in general. :-)